# This JS code works properly in the .cshtml file, but not working in .js file(external javascript file)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-3.0, jsonresult

This JS code works properly in the .cshtml file, but not working in .js file(external javascript file). Can anyone help me? i am also trying with Ajax GET but also not working in js file

```
[Area("Administrator")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public JsonResult EarningChart()
    {
        var earning = _context.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == OrderStatus.Completed).ToList();
        return Json (earning);
    }
```

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //ajax function for fetch data
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("EarningChart","Home",new { area ="Administrator"})',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('succeed');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Failed');
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: This isn't Javascript. It's C#. That's why it doesn't work in a .js file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` is razor (server side) code and can't be used in .js file .You can add a hidden field in your main page to store url, then use javascript/jquery to get the url from the hidden field in .js file :

```
@Html.Hidden("MyURL", Url.Action("EarningChart","Home",,new { area ="Administrator"}))
```

Then in your js file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var myUrl = $("#MyURL").val();
        //ajax function for fetch data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: myUrl,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('succeed');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any js file or any cshtml file

From your comments I see you have :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { //ajax function for fetch data $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: '@Url.Action("EarningChart","Home",new { area ="Administrator"})', success: function (data) { alert('succeed'); }, error: function () { alert('failed'); } }); }); </script>
```

I will assume your question is that if you have above code in your cshtml file it works but if you have above code in a seperate js file it doesn't  work

In order to include your js file you need to include it in your cshtml page like this:

```
<script src="yourJsFilePathHere"></script>
```

Comment: Dear, I am given the js code in the post some minute ago. I already used this js directly in the cshtml. and it's working. But i am trying to use this code in javascript file and linked that script file in the cshtml, but isn't working